# Pass by reference for nodes in java linked list

Tags: java, data-structures

```
private Node<T> copyList(Node<T> cn1) {
    Node<T> temp = cn1;
    Node<T> newHead = null;
    Node<T> end = null;     
    newHead = new Node<T>((T)(temp.x).clone(), null);

    end = newHead;
    temp = temp.next;

    while (temp != null) {
        end.next = new Node<T>((T)(temp.x).clone(), null);

        end = end.next;
        temp = temp.next;
    }

    // Now the entire list is created, just return its head pointer
    return newHead;
}
```

The method is trying to make deep copies for generic nodes in a `LinkedList`, the method is correct and I'm just confused about the line `end = newHead;`. Shouldn't `end` and `newHead` reference the same object? Why is the line `end = end.next;` not updating `newHead`?

I'm sorry if the question is too obvious.

Comment: "*shouldn't end and newHead reference the same object*" - No. The head references the first item in the list (this is why `newHead` is only assigned once, making it effectively `final`). Reference `end` references the last `Node` in the list, i.e. where to append new `Node` s.

Comment: Thanks a lot for commenting, I was under the impression that when we write object1 = object2 then both will have the same reference and changing one would affect the other. Can you please explain why is that no the case here for the line end = newHead ?

Comment: This is the first item added. If the `List` only has one item, then `head` and `end` are the same.

Answer (score 0):

When you write something like:

`Node x = new Node();`

Where Node is **NOT** a primitive (so not int, long, boolean, etc),

you should mentally model that as:

We create some new treasure (`new Node();`) - we conjure up a treasure box out of thin air. It has no name; treasures never have names. You bury it in the sand.

Separately, this also declares that you have a treasure map on you, which you've labelled `x` (maps have names; treasures do not). You draw a map to the site you just buried your newly created treasure on this map.

Then, the `.` operator is the 'follow the map and dig' operator, whereas e.g. the `=` operator is the 'wipe out your map and overwrite it with how to get to some other treasure'.

With 'treasure' = object, and 'map' = variables and expressions.

For example,  `List<List<String>>` is not really a 'list of a list of strings'. It's a list (treasure) that contains **treasure maps**, not a treasure holding treasures.

For your specific question:

`end = newHead;` is wiping out whatever the treasure map named `end` had (it does **NOT** follow the `end` map and do anything to the treasure you find there!) - and overwrites the map with the exact same map that `newHead` is. Now if you were to follow the `newHead` map, you get to the same treasure as if you followed the `end` map. To follow maps, you use the `.` (or, technically, array access, synchronized, throw, and foreach, which also follow maps and operate on the treasure it leads to).

So, you have 2 treasure maps, that currently lead to the same treasure.

Then you do: `end = end.next;`. This does *NOT* follow the map to the treasure. This modifies the treasure map itself: end is wiped out and now is a map to the treasure that the `end.next` map leads to.

`end.next` is like this: "Take the map named `end`. Follow the map, and dig down. Open the treasure chest. Inside, you will find **another** treasure map by looking in the little box labelled 'next' inside the treasure chest. In this code (`end = end.next;`) that treasure map is never followed, it's just copied onto the `end` map you've got on you, which wipes out what `end` was pointing at before.

Answer (score 0):

This is the situation after `end = newHead;`:

[image: after end = newHead;]

`newHead` and `end` are 2 different references that point at the same object (the head of the list).

This is the situation after `end = end.next;`:

[image: after end = end.next;]

`end` is now pointing to the next node. `newHead` is unaffected since it is a
different reference so it keeps pointing what it was pointing before.